# Finding matches that contain certain text in properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am trying to convert the following code to `LINQ`

```
foreach (var item in pageHistorycol)
    {
        if (item.PageTitle.Contains(text) || item.PageURI.Contains(text))
        {
            tempHistory.Insert(0, item);
        }
    }
```

The following returns all items instead of the matches

```
var matches = pageHistorycol.Where(item => 
    (item.PageTitle.Contains(text) || item.PageURI.Contains(text)));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Other than the order being different, those two should return the same items...

Comment: But the second one always return all items

Comment: Then something else is going on here...

Comment: You are right because now the first one also return all items.., it was ok previously..  am checking

Answer (score 0):

The two statements you displayed should return the same items.  If the second returns all items, the foreach loop should add all of the items to `tempHistory` as well.

The main difference will be your `foreach` loop will return the items in the opposite order as your LINQ query.  If the order of matches is important, you can get the items in the same order using:

```
var matches = pageHistorycol
     .Where(item => item.PageTitle.Contains(text) || item.PageURI.Contains(text))
     .Reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but for some reason it returns no matches. Checked it again using `foreach` and that works...

Comment: @PutraKg How are you **using** the results?  LINQ has deferred execution - try adding `.ToList()` to the end, as that forces it to execute fully right away.